# How to remove ms-cui-disabled from a button?

Tags: ribbon

The Workflow button is currently disabled on a list, in all views. It is using the "ms-cui-ctl-large ms-cui-disabledcui-disabled" CSS. Where do I go to change this to the class="ms-cui-ctl-large " ? In SharePoint Designer? I found this by using Firebug, but I can't determine how this was changed as there's no CEWP on the page calling a script.

```
  <a id="Ribbon.ListItem.Workflow.ViewWorkflows-Large" class="ms-cui-ctl-large ms-cui-disabled" unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" aria-describedby="Ribbon.ListItem.Workflow.ViewWorkflows_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your workflow button is disabled it's likely being disabled by SharePoint intentionally due to an issue with the workflow, no workflows enabled, or you not having access to the workflow. It could also be disabled at a higher level through a custom action or configuration.

Simply changing the ms-cui-disabled class or removing it from the button isn't going to actually enable any capability, it'll just change the appearance of the button. You can use the SharePoint CSOM to set the button to enabled, or do it through a custom action, but it's likely disabled by SharePoint intentionally.

Comment: Thanks webdes03. I'm going to have to blame SharePoint I suppose since there was no custom programming on the list itself. It doesn't solve my dilemma of not being able to start new workflows though. I might have to recreate the list itself.

Comment: I found it. It was a Custom Action as you had thought. Thanks again for the help.